# $this.val() not getting jQuery-generated form value

Tags: jquery, ajax

The first script turns text into an editable text field when clicked. After the text is edited a submit button is pressed that activates the second script. The second script should send some info to another page via AJAX to be eventually submitted into a database. The first two variables (projectID and contactType) are sent through the AJAX just fine, but updatedInfo (the variable that's supposed to have the edited text in it) is always blank. I'm assuming it's something stupid I'm missing but I can't figure it out. The two scripts are below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var alreadyActive = "";
        $(".editable").on("click", function () {
            if(!alreadyActive) {
                OriginalText = $(this).text();
                divValue = $(this).attr('value');
                $(this).html("<form class='edit-form' name='" + divValue + "'><input type='text' value='" + OriginalText + "' /><input type='submit' value='Update' /></form>");
                alreadyActive = "true";
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('body').delegate('.edit-form','submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var projectID = <?php echo $projectID ?>;
        var contactType = $(this).attr('name');
        var updatedInfo = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'editinplace.php?projectID=' + projectID + '&contactType=' + contactType + '&updatedInfo=' + updatedInfo,
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're trying to get the value of the text field inside the form, then you want to change:

```
var updatedInfo = $(this).val();
```

to:

```
var updatedInfo = $(this).find('input[type="text"]:first').val();
```

What your code is doing is looking for a `value` attribute on the `<form>` tag itself. Instead, since the `value` you're after is located in the `<input>` tag, you have to get jQuery to go look at that specific tag.

Answer (score 0):

it actually looks like you are getting the 'value' of the form

```
var updatedInfo = $(this).val();
```

'this' (if i am reading the code correctly) would be the form, not the input.  and like mentioned by the others answering to get the text of a button try $(this).text()

Comment: I had tried $(this).text() prior to posting. Coby's answered worked perfectly, thanks for answering though.